# Compilation error when saving my project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, salesforce

I'm using Eclipse Luna and am getting the following error when I try to save my `FORCE.COM` project:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Compilation error: Unknown property 'StandardController.jQueryUIDateFormat' myPage.page /myProject/src/pages    line 1  Force.com compilation problem
```

Does this look familiar to anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a compilation trouble with `OpportunityStandardController` and `myPage.page`, so there are no issues with Eclipse. Try to save these components in turn. The other ability is saving these files from developer console.